# How to print $data->id in label yii

Tags: yii, printing, label

How to print `$data->id` in label yii in php like this

```
<label>Your ID is <?php echo $id ?> </label>
```

so, how to use in yii ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$labelQuote =  'Your ID is '. $data->id;
echo CHtml::label($labelQuote, 'for_some_id');
```